# Laravel - inner groupBy on collection

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have table with matches between players, with fields:

ID | player1_id | player2_id | scoreP1 | score P2 | stage

1 | dummy1 | dummy2 | 2 | 3 | ROUND16

2 | random2 | test1 | 2 | 1 | ROUND16

3 | dummy2 | dummy1 | 1 | 1 | ROUND16

4 | test1 | random2 | 2 | 3 | ROUND16

5 | random2 | dummy2 | 1 | 1 | ROUND8

6 | dummy2 | random2 | 1 | 3 | ROUND8

Now value for stages are ROUND16, ROUND8, ROUND4, ROUND2, FINAL. Those value represent stages of a tournament. Now I group matches into groups for each stage. Each match between players happens twice, once player is "home" and other time "away". For example player Dummy would once be under player1_id other time under player2_id.

This is how I group matches into groups of stages.

```
$matches=Match::where('stage','ROUND_OF_16')->get();

$stages = $matches->mapToGroups(function ($item, $key) {
                return [$item['stage'] => $item];
            });
```

Now what I want to do is to group those two matches together inside a group ROUND16. So I would get groups for rounds and inside groups with paired matches. Problem is that player is one time under player1_id and other time under player2_id so I can't figure out how to group this two matches together.

And end result:

ROUND16{

[0]{

[id:1,player1_id:dummy1,player2_id:dummy2]

[id:3,player1_id:dummy2,player2_id:dummy1]

}

[1]{

[id:2,player1_id:random2,player2_id:test1]

[id:4,player1_id:test1,player2_id:random2]

}

}

ROUND8{

[0]{

[id:5,player1_id:random2,player2_id:dummy2]

[id:6,player1_id:dummy2,player2_id:random2]

}

}

Comment: Can you give your current table data sample and the resultant sample structure you are looking to get? That will make so much clear what query you need to do.

Comment: It'd be useful for you to add a column `key` so, you relate both record (home and away). `ID | player1_id | player2_id | scoreP1 | score P2 | key | stage`, with this you could do `return [$item['stage'] => [$item['key'] => [$item]]];` in the `mapTogroups` function. Haven't use that function yet, but in case this doesn't work, just make another `->mapToGroups` to accomplish the desired result.

Comment: @MihirBhende Edited post

Comment: @HCK data comes from API so I can't change that

Comment: @Miko `player1_id`/`player2_id` are integers or strings?

Comment: @HCK both are intergers